# Click link inside div that shows when input field is in focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

So simple CSS here to show a div when the input is in focus:

```css
.ulclass {
  background: #f0a;
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
form:focus-within + ul.ulclass {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="Enter some text here" class="inputclass">
</form>
<ul class="ulclass">
  <a href="https://google.com">link</a>
</ul>
```

I have a link inside the div being shown, however I'm not able to click it because doing so blurs the input field before the link is fired. Anyone got any suggestions on how to do this better?

Answer (score 5):

Add the `ulclass` with a `:hover` pseudo class to the `focus` rule:

```css
.ulclass {
  background: #f0a;
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
form:focus-within + ul.ulclass, ul.ulclass:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="Enter some text here" class="inputclass">
</form>
<ul class="ulclass">
  <a href="https://google.com">link</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: wonderful, thanks so much! Been rattling my brain for a couple hours!

Comment: Note that [`focus-within` is non-standard and doesn't work in any MS browser (including Edge)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within#Specifications).

Answer (score 2):

You can display the `div` with JavaScript, not CSS. Also, separate out the `display:none;` instruction into its own CSS class, so that it can be removed without also removing the rest of the style.

**This approach is standard and will work in all clients.**

```js
document.querySelector("input.inputclass").addEventListener("focus", function(){
  document.querySelector(".ulclass").classList.remove("hidden");
});
```

```css
.ulclass {
  background: #f0a;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.hidden {  display: none; }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="Enter some text here" class="inputclass">
</form>
<ul class="ulclass hidden">
  <a href="https://google.com">link</a>
</ul>
```